# Acetylacetonato or Acetylacetonate

Tags: nomenclature

I'm currently working on a project using [Iron(III) acetylacetonate](https://www.sigmaaldrich.com/catalog/product/aldrich/f300?lang=es&region=ES), which in the wikipedia page it's written [Tris(acetylacetonato)iron(III)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tris(acetylacetonato)iron(III)), and it says it's the IUPAC name, maybe it's obvious but I'm a little confused about the nomenclature, why acetylacetonato instead of acetylacetonate, couldn't it be Tris(acetylacetonate)iron(III)? Is one name better than the other?

Comment: In IUPAC nomenclature, anionic ligands generally end in -o (-ido, -ito or -ato). See [this](https://chem.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Inorganic_Chemistry/Supplemental_Modules_(Inorganic_Chemistry)/Coordination_Chemistry/Structure_and_Nomenclature_of_Coordination_Compounds/Nomenclature_of_Coordination_Complexes) for reference.

Comment: Both can be used. See: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/5039/where-did-the-acac-come-from-in-cracac%e2%82%83-synthesis-by-crcl%e2%82%83-reagent/5040#5040

Comment: It should be used interchangeably otherwise in Italian and probably Spanish we would miss a class. - ate already sounds - ato and I don't know what - ato ENG change into IT

Comment: Thank you, I knew it was simple, I guess it's a problem of having studied chemistry in a different language, it wasn't obvious for me. I understand then that both are correct, being the latter the normative IUPAC name, and the first one the _easy_, common name.